# Truncated backpropagation in PyTorch (code check)

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation

I am trying to implement truncated backpropagation through time in PyTorch, for the simple case where `K1=K2`. I have an implementation below that produces reasonable output, but I just want to make sure it is correct. When I look online for PyTorch examples of TBTT, they do inconsistent things around detaching the hidden state and zeroing out the gradient, and the ordering of these operations. Please let me know if I have made a mistake.

In the code below, `H` maintains the current hidden state, and `model(weights, H, x)` outputs the prediction and the new hidden state.

```
while i < NUM_STEPS:
    # Grab x, y for ith datapoint
    x = data[i]
    target = true_output[i]

    # Run model
    output, new_hidden = model(weights, H, x)
    H = new_hidden

    # Update running error
    error += (output - target)**2

    if (i+1) % K == 0:
        # Backpropagate
        error.backward()
        opt.step()
        opt.zero_grad()
        error = 0
        H = H.detach()

    i += 1
```

Comment: If you are using baches `(output - target)**2` returns a tensor. Not sure if `error.backward()` will work then. You can fix it by taking the average error `error += ((output - target)**2).mean() `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the idea of your code is to isolate the last variables after each Kth step. Yes, your implementation is absolutely correct and this [answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/correct-way-to-do-backpropagation-through-time/11701/3) confirms that.

```py
# truncated to the last K timesteps
while i < NUM_STEPS:
    out = model(out)
    if (i+1) % K == 0:
        out.backward()
        out.detach()
out.backward()
```

You can also follow [this](https://github.com/pytorch/ignite/blob/master/ignite/contrib/engines/tbptt.py) example for your reference.

```py
import torch

from ignite.engine import Engine, EventEnum, _prepare_batch
from ignite.utils import apply_to_tensor


class Tbptt_Events(EventEnum):
    """Aditional tbptt events.

    Additional events for truncated backpropagation throught time dedicated
    trainer.
    """

    TIME_ITERATION_STARTED = "time_iteration_started"
    TIME_ITERATION_COMPLETED = "time_iteration_completed"


def _detach_hidden(hidden):
    """Cut backpropagation graph.

    Auxillary function to cut the backpropagation graph by detaching the hidden
    vector.
    """
    return apply_to_tensor(hidden, torch.Tensor.detach)


def create_supervised_tbptt_trainer(
    model, optimizer, loss_fn, tbtt_step, dim=0, device=None, non_blocking=False, prepare_batch=_prepare_batch
):
    """Create a trainer for truncated backprop through time supervised models.

    Training recurrent model on long sequences is computationally intensive as
    it requires to process the whole sequence before getting a gradient.
    However, when the training loss is computed over many outputs
    (`X to many <https://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/>`_),
    there is an opportunity to compute a gradient over a subsequence. This is
    known as
    `truncated backpropagation through time <https://machinelearningmastery.com/
    gentle-introduction-backpropagation-time/>`_.
    This supervised trainer apply gradient optimization step every `tbtt_step`
    time steps of the sequence, while backpropagating through the same
    `tbtt_step` time steps.

    Args:
        model (`torch.nn.Module`): the model to train.
        optimizer (`torch.optim.Optimizer`): the optimizer to use.
        loss_fn (torch.nn loss function): the loss function to use.
        tbtt_step (int): the length of time chunks (last one may be smaller).
        dim (int): axis representing the time dimension.
        device (str, optional): device type specification (default: None).
            Applies to batches.
        non_blocking (bool, optional): if True and this copy is between CPU and GPU,
            the copy may occur asynchronously with respect to the host. For other cases,
            this argument has no effect.
        prepare_batch (callable, optional): function that receives `batch`, `device`,
            `non_blocking` and outputs tuple of tensors `(batch_x, batch_y)`.

    .. warning::

        The internal use of `device` has changed.
        `device` will now *only* be used to move the input data to the correct device.
        The `model` should be moved by the user before creating an optimizer.

        For more information see:

        * `PyTorch Documentation <https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#constructing-it>`_
        * `PyTorch's Explanation <https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7844#issuecomment-503713840>`_

    Returns:
        Engine: a trainer engine with supervised update function.

    """

    def _update(engine, batch):
        loss_list = []
        hidden = None

        x, y = batch
        for batch_t in zip(x.split(tbtt_step, dim=dim), y.split(tbtt_step, dim=dim)):
            x_t, y_t = prepare_batch(batch_t, device=device, non_blocking=non_blocking)
            # Fire event for start of iteration
            engine.fire_event(Tbptt_Events.TIME_ITERATION_STARTED)
            # Forward, backward and
            model.train()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            if hidden is None:
                y_pred_t, hidden = model(x_t)
            else:
                hidden = _detach_hidden(hidden)
                y_pred_t, hidden = model(x_t, hidden)
            loss_t = loss_fn(y_pred_t, y_t)
            loss_t.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # Setting state of engine for consistent behaviour
            engine.state.output = loss_t.item()
            loss_list.append(loss_t.item())

            # Fire event for end of iteration
            engine.fire_event(Tbptt_Events.TIME_ITERATION_COMPLETED)

        # return average loss over the time splits
        return sum(loss_list) / len(loss_list)

    engine = Engine(_update)
    engine.register_events(*Tbptt_Events)
    return engine
```