# How to run LSTM on very long sequence using Truncated Backpropagation in Pytorch (lightning)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, pytorch-lightning

I have a very long time series I want to feed into an LSTM for classification per-frame.

My data is labeled per frame, and I know some rare events happen that influence the classification heavily ever since they occur.

Thus, I have to feed the entire sequence to get meaningful predictions.

It is known that just feeding very long sequences into LSTM is sub-optimal, since the gradients vanish or explode just like normal RNNs.

---

I wanted to use a simple technique of cutting the sequence to shorter (say, 100-long) sequences, and run the LSTM on each, then pass the final LSTM hidden and cell states as the start hidden and cell state of the next forward pass.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62901561/truncated-backpropagation-in-pytorch-code-check) is an example I found of someone who did just that. There it is called "Truncated Back propagation through time". I was not able to make the same work for me.

---

My attempt in Pytorch lightning (stripped of irrelevant parts):

```
def __init__(self, config, n_classes, datamodule):
    ...
    self._criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(
        reduction='mean',
    )

    num_layers = 1
    hidden_size = 50
    batch_size=1

    self._lstm1 = nn.LSTM(input_size=len(self._in_features), hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, batch_first=True)
    self._log_probs = nn.Linear(hidden_size, self._n_predicted_classes)
    self._last_h_n = torch.zeros((num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size), device='cuda', dtype=torch.double, requires_grad=False)
    self._last_c_n = torch.zeros((num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size), device='cuda', dtype=torch.double, requires_grad=False)

def training_step(self, batch, batch_index):
    orig_batch, label_batch = batch
    n_labels_in_batch = np.prod(label_batch.shape)
    lstm_out, (self._last_h_n, self._last_c_n) = self._lstm1(orig_batch, (self._last_h_n, self._last_c_n))
    log_probs = self._log_probs(lstm_out)
    loss = self._criterion(log_probs.view(n_labels_in_batch, -1), label_batch.view(n_labels_in_batch))

    return loss
```

Running this code gives the following error:

> ```
> RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.
> ```

The same happens if I add

```
def on_after_backward(self) -> None:
    self._last_h_n.detach()
    self._last_c_n.detach()
```

The error does not happen if I use

```
lstm_out, (self._last_h_n, self._last_c_n) = self._lstm1(orig_batch,)
```

But obviously this is useless, as the output from the current frame-batch is not forwarded to the next one.

---

What is causing this error? I thought detaching the output `h_n` and `c_n` should be enough.

How do I pass the output of a previous frame-batch to the next one and have torch back propagate each frame batch separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I missed the trailing `_` for `detach()`:

Using

```
def on_after_backward(self) -> None:
    self._last_h_n.detach_()
    self._last_c_n.detach_()
```

works.

---

The problem was `self._last_h_n.detach()` does not update the reference to the *new memory* allocated by detach(), thus the graph is still de-referencing the old variable which backprop went through.
[The reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62901561/truncated-backpropagation-in-pytorch-code-check) solved that by `H = H.detach()`.

Cleaner (and probably faster) is `self._last_h_n.detach_()` which does the operation in place.